# How to weigh the data queryset count for paging policy?

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a User model that has 20 count field:

```
class User(models.Model):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)  # sha1 
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True,blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField( max_length=11)   
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True )
    qq = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)   
    id_card = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=18, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{18}$', message='身份证长度必须为18', code='nomatch')])
    id_card_img_front = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    id_card_img_back = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True, default=' ')   
    usertype = models.ForeignKey(to='UserType', default=1, blank=True)  

    user_c_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)   
    fixed_phone = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)   
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True) 
    main_bussiness = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)  
    main_industry = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True) 
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)  
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)  
    province = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default="--省--")   
    town = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default="--市--")  # 省市县
    country_level = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default="--县--")   

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)    
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, default=1)
```

And in my Django project, I want to use Paginator to realize paging for user list.

Because the count of my user in my database is no more than 10,000 rows.

So, whether I can get all of the user in my database then paginate them?

```
user_all =  models.User.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(user_all, 10)

try:
    user_list_page = paginator.page(page_number)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    user_list_page = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    user_list_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

And I don't know whether this method(query out all the rows of user data) is inefficiency.

Or, how to weight the balance of query out the users from database? For a positive limit numbers ( over the count I should change paginate method, less than that I can use my page method )?

Or is there a better method to paginate my users?

Comment: It's not clear what you think is wrong with this. That is how you are supposed to use paginators. And it isn't fetching all the rows of your users.

Comment: Do you mean use my method is correct and efficiently?  because I think use `models.User.objects.all()` will fetch all the users data from my database. You means it only fetch 10(page_size) rows user data? if like you says, how can Paginator implement this?

Comment: Querysets are lazy; `User.objects.all()` does not actually do a query.

Comment: @DanielRoseman so my method is best . no need to optimize

Answer (score 0):

The generic `ListView` brings a paginator. You should make sure that your queryset is sorted, otherwise the pages might repeat some of the objects (that is not a Django issue - paging without a sort order is just not practical).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class UserListView(ListView):
    template = 'my_user_list_template.html'
    model = User  # not django.contrib.User but your's
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by('realname', 'pk')
```

The template will contain all context data required to render pagination, and the max 10 objects for the current page.

There are 3rd party modules like `pure_pagination` that extend the pagination to allow for other GET parameters in the pagination links: https://github.com/jamespacileo/django-pure-pagination

More links:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by
See also on the same page: `paginate_orphans`, `paginator_class` etc.